# bootstrap Carousel doesn`t work, shows pictures in one colmn

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I want to program my own website and having trouble to add tha carousel on my landing page. 
It should be a fullscreen carousel which shows 3 different images one after another by either clicking or the images sliding by them self after a few seconds. I have used the help of bootstrap by using their plugin for carousel and have done everything exactly like it been told in their description but my carousel doesn`t work. It showing me my pictures in a column by swiping down the page. I have no idea what I have done wrong. Can please someone help me?

my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carousel_selftest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel_selftest.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slie-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slie-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="Mockup_Magazin.png" alt="project1" width="1680px" height="1383,53px">
        </div>

        <div class="item2">
            <img src="infografic_1.png" alt="project2" width="1680px" height="1383,53px">
        </div>

        <div class="item3">
            <img src="PEVUO01.png" alt="project3" width="1680px" height="1383,53px">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left-carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right-carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in my css I have add only this

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
.container
{
    display: grid;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.mycarousel
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 632px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: The solution below is working right??

Comment: welll it's the same way which I have done and for me it doesn't work :/

Comment: I have edited it check now!!!

Answer (score 1):

you tag bootstrap-4 but use bootstrap-3 in youre code!!!!

in bootstrap-3 use this link to Correction youre core
[w3schools_bootstrap_carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because I have used exactly the same link which you have sent me and done it same way how it been told there. Can you tell me what exactly I have to change in my code that it work?

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

Its a 2 seconds slide time , which stops on hover only

download the images from the src links and try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .a {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000" data-pause="hover" data-wrap="true">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block a " src="168.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block a" src="167.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block  a" src="169.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a> -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                ************sometext****************
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ************sometext****************
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                ************sometext****************
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ************sometext****************
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ************sometext****************
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

click :https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/vrgfupea/1/